# how to move functions to a separated file Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which is used in several files, in it I use `setState(() {});` and some variables that are in the file, can I somehow separate it into another file and call it from there, and not write it on each page?

Here is an example of my function:

```
  Future addToFav(productId, int index) async {
    var url =
        '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=favorite_toggle&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}&product_id=$productId';
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );
    dynamic body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(body['success']);
    print(body['message']);
    if(body['message'] == 'ADDED') {
      setState(() => _isFavLoading.add(index));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isFavLoading.remove(index);
          isFavorite = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot update the state with `setState()` outside of the widget. You have to pass the logic that updates the state as parameter to the function, so you will get such function:

```
Future<void> addToFav({
  required int productId,
  required int index,
  VoidCallback? onAdded,
  VoidCallback? onRemoved,
}) async {
  var url =
      '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=favorite_toggle&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}&product_id=$productId';
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  dynamic body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(body['success']);
  print(body['message']);
  if (body['message'] == 'ADDED') {
    onAdded?.call();
  } else {
    onRemoved?.call();
  }
}
```

In the widget you will call this function like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      addToFav(
        index: index,
        productId: productId,
        onAdded: () {
          setState(() => _isFavLoading.add(index));
        },
        onRemoved: () {
          setState(() {
            _isFavLoading.remove(index);
            isFavorite = false;
          });
        },
      );
    },
    child: Text('Fav'),
  )
```